# How to swap the elements in a list while keeping their index the same if you don't know the index (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Say I have these two lists:

```
list1=["Green","2","Blue","4"]
list2=["1","Orange","3","red"]
```

If I wanted to swap the '3' with 'blue' how would I do if it if I don't already know the positions of the elements in the list?

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Are you trying to swap a **specific** item from the first list with the matching one in the second list (or vice-versa)?

Comment: What are the criteria for swapping?

Comment: Why don't you know the index, can you please make some context for your use case? For better understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1=["Green","2","Blue","4"]
list2=["1","Orange","3","red"]

l1 = list1.index("Blue")
l2 = list2.index("3")

list1[l1], list2[l2] = list2[l2], list1[l1]
```